# My project is not compatible with netstandard2.1. My project supports: netcore 3.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard

I am developing a project in .Net core 3.0. When I am trying to add a reference to a .net standard class library, I encounter this error:

[image: img]

I am using VS 2019 - Console Application Core 3.1 and 3 - .Net Standard 2.0 and 2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can reference the class library to your project.

Alternatively you can try deleting the Dotnet Core from Your machine and reinstall it

Comment: The main problem is the overlapping versions of libraries.
I did not see this problem when the new .NET Core came. thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

The error says that you have added a reference to the `ConsoleApp11` project in the `NetStandard` library. You cannot do this.

You need to add a reference to the `NetStandard` library in the `ConsoleApp11` project.

**This is wrong**

[image: References the wrong way round]

The `ClassLibrary` has a reference to the `ConsoleApp11` project - which is causing the error

**This is correct**

[image: Correct references]

The `ConsoleApp` project has a reference to the `ClassLibrary` project

Comment: I need reference ConsoleApp in my ClassLibrary for unit testing.

Comment: @mehrshadfarzaneh then you wont be able to do this and your probably have the design backwards... interns of what references what and why.... libs are reference by apps not the other way around a console app is an app and not a lib. the answer above is quite gd as it added pics to show.

Comment: your test lib should be referencing your lib and not console, as that wouldn't make sense, if you have logic in ur console app, then u should of created a service in your lib which is where the logic sits... which is what you wanting to test, hence why it would be the lib instead of the console.

Comment: @Seabizkit yes I want to use class library for test. hes answer is wrong. If you have a solution can you explain it easier? my English is not good as yours.